# Mongoose work around to no schema registered

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 schemas: Customer and Address. For other reasons the address schema must be registered first.
How can i perform a query on the customer table within a static in the address schema?

I am thinking I need to access the raw mongo driver and perform a query using that - I don't need any special Mongoose validation/middleware so that is not an issue.

How would I access the Address table using the native driver inside of the Customer model? Or is there a pure Mongoose way of doing this?  Note that O do not want to create refs in the Customer table to address and use population.

Comment: Generally address would be included in the customer document. There is no need to reference different documents, this isn't an SQL database.

Comment: I am not asking for joins or schema layout - i have a need to call another schema that, for technical reasons, cannot be registered first.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to access the Address model from the customer.js model.

```
//Customer.js

var Address = require('./models/Address');

CustomerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    addresses: [{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Address'}]
});

CustomerSchema.statics.getAddressById = function getAddressById (id, next) {
    Customer.findOne({_id: id}, function (err, customer) {
        if (err || !customer) {
            return next(err || new Error('Customer not found with id' + id));
        }

        Address.find({_id: {$in : customer.addresses}}, next);
    }); 
}

var Customer = db.model('Customer', CustomerSchema);
module.exports = Customer;
```

I'm assuming your customer schema has an `addresses` key that is an array of addresses. if this isn't the case, feel free to change it to a single address.

Comment: The Address schema is not yet registered (i.e. no db.model('Address', Address. I register all the schemas once on load since you can only require the model once.  Also this is not a ref issue. Just trying to avoid having a wrapper around the model just for the sake of calling another model. But I may have to.

Comment: You can require the model as often as you want. Node caches its requires, so it doesn't re-instantiate a new model every time you require it. requiring Address registers the Address model. If you want to do it without, use the mongodb native driver, and just do db.addresses.find({_id: {$in: customer.addresses})})

Comment: Is this a recent change? Mongoose in the past has not allowed this - creates mutiple registration issues. I had to load all my mongoose models in one place once to avoid the endless errors. This was a well known issue. For ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277683/call-require-on-mongoose-model-more-than-once

Comment: In that sense(the example), you are exporting a function every time. In the example I gave, you're just exporting the model, not declaring the schema multiple times. It's a singleton approach. I've been using it for a long time, and haven't had any issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I was able to solve my issue by changing where I made the call to `var Customer = mongoose.model('Customer')` call. Placing this at the top of my Address model with all other require caused a schema registration error. But placing it right inside the static method did the trick.

So:

```
AddressSchema.statics.myMethod = function() {
  var Customer = mongoose.model('Customer');
```